Soldiers bred for battle are killed when peace begins
Short(ish) story I read in the late 1980s, I can't remember anything else in the anthology, this was from a UK library.
It begins with a battle between Space Marine type soldiers and aliens on a deserted moon.
A signal is given and combat stops for a while.
An Earth soldier checks his weapon and looks for his unit, he spots a badly wounded barracks buddy but his colleague has been tagged as unsalvageable by the battlefield medics (I think all the soldiers only had serial numbers, no names) so he walks away.
He reminisces about good times they'd had together in the camp brothels, the women were near mindless with unshaved legs and hardly any speech.
The aliens surrender and the decades long war is over, one day he is summoned to Command HQ and an array of high level officers are there, along with a very attractive female (maybe a politician)
They are there to assess if these soldiers can be assimilated into society, they've been raised to kill since infanthood.
She can't believe how magnificent he looks but a conversation reveals he and his colleagues are very dangerous.
He is dismissed and after a discussion they decide there's only one option with the millions of soldiers scattered throughout space.
A general order is given and all these brave young men are gassed to death while they're asleep in their bunks.

Could be Your Soldier Unto Death by Michael Walker. Published in If., Oct 1966.

To meet the personnel requirements, virtually the entire male portion of the human race has come to be tied up in the service of Man.
They are trained from birth, and their training consists of two parts. The first is the complete focusing of all emotion into a single drive to destroy Kreekan soldier-forms, and the second is the development of the physical and technical prowess necessary to implement the first. In short, the infants are reared so that their only feeling is one of enmity toward the Kreekal, and their only skill is a propensity for destroying Kreekal. They are exact counterparts of the Kreekan soldier forms. They are machines designed to serve one purpose, and with the end of the war that purpose has ceased to exist. They no longer have an object in life."

In the end the "magnificent man" is listed for euthanasia - by gas.

They went into the inner office together.
"I suppose she represents the typical reaction, to the soldier,"
Chalmers remarked when the door was closed. "A magnificent, pathetic creature whose way of life offends her sense of propriety and whose intelligence is oriented in a way she can't comprehend."
The general had not heard. "I won't let them die," he whispered. It was his duty to say it.
"The nerve gas is painless and instantaneous," Chalmers said, disregarding the general and disregarding something within himself that echoed the general's words. "Several bases have already been treated. The exterminators are orbiting a few thousand miles out. I'll have them come down tomorrow morning. It will be over in a few minutes."
"I can't let them die."
"Yes you can," said Chalmers heavily.
"We all can. We have to."


The story can be read online here; https://galacticjourney.org/stories/1966,%2010%20(October),%20If.pdf

I've taken the liberty of editing in some quotes. Good find ;-)

This has to be a Kreekan plot to destroy humanity.

@RonJohn: my thoughts exactly! My first thought when reading this answer was "They'd better hope that the Kreekal don't find out that they just destroyed their entire army". And reading the full story didn't assuage my doubts...

@rob74 I was thinking more of there not being any more (or too few) men to make the next generation, but yeah, "destroy the army" is certainly an immediate threat.
